# What is the better form to write Loop functions end with pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I know two forms to write loop functions with pointers in c++: using size of array or using the end of array.

Use the length:

```
float summationArray(float* numbers, int length){
  if(length == 1){
    return *numbers;
  }

  return *numbers + summationArray(numbers + 1, length - 1);
}
```

Use the end

```
float summationArray(float* numbers, float* end){
  if(numbers == end){
    return *numbers;
  }

  return *numbers + summationArray(numbers + 1, end);
}
```

What's is the better option?

Comment: Using an open range `[begin, end)` see most of the C++ Standard algorithms. Note that pointers are random access iterators.

Comment: Better means the ideal form to write a function, like seniors programmers write.

Comment: I wouldn't accept both variants in a code review. Most C++ developers expect `end` to be after the last element. In this case you should prefer loops instead of recursion. Your code requires a random access iterator even though it could be solved with a simple forward iterator.

Comment: @jabaa, how you would accept?

Comment: @CharlesBraga `float const total = std::accumulate(start, one_past_the_end, 0f);` would be the C++17 way.

Comment: That's how I would implement my own summation function https://wandbox.org/permlink/o92f953GjzIHVvX3 but of course you should prefer an STL algorithm https://wandbox.org/permlink/jTO3UE2HTrZ2RWvU

Comment: Both of your code can't handle empty arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre C++20, two iterators are better because they allow the function work on all types of iterators even those that don't know the size of the range. This is the convention most of the standard library follows.

Post C++20, you would probably use a [range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range).

PS: Don't use recursion to calculate a sum. That's a bad idea. Use `std::accumulate` or at least a proper iterative loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think one option is strictly better than the other, but the idiomatic approach in C++ is usually to use a pointer ("iterator") to the start and end of the container. Compare, e.g., with [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Answer (score 1):

From a perspective on how they manage resources they are the same, so studying them from a time complexity point... they are the same too, the main difference on this to methods is how you obtain the size or the end pointer,  but you only need to do it once, so the time it takes related to the size of the array will not change, cause is a single operation for the hole execution of the algorithm.

So calling them (when not having the size in a variable) looks like:

```
float value = summationArray(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
float value = summationArray(array, std::end(array));
```

So I think, I would go with the end option, since it  looks more """"pro""""", it's cleaner and is more c++ style.